# update function throwing erro(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am having a problem that when ever I call the update function it throws an error. I have tried to find the solution but I could'nt find it and I can't understad the error. Please tell me what is wrong with the code

The update function is called from this function

```
  def bookmark_request
    data = params[:d]
    request_bookmarked = Request.getRequest(data)
    bookmarked_against_Request = Request.first
    request_bookmarked_2 = request_bookmarked
    bookmarked_against_Request_2 = bookmarked_against_Request

    if bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites]
      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << bookmarked_against_Request[:id]
    else
      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] = Array.new
      bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << bookmarked_against_Request[:id]
    end


    Request.updateRequest(bookmarked_against_Request , bookmarked_against_Request_2)
    redirect_to :action => "active"
  end
```

and the update code is this

```
def updateRequest(request,req_data)
 if request.update(req_data)
  request
 end
end
```

The error that I am getting is this

**NoMethodError at requests/bookmark_request

undefined method `empty?' for Request:0x007f3fa44c59b0**

The error always comes on the line if request.update(req_data)

Sice I do not have a reputation of 10 so I am posting links to screenshot of the error
http://tinypic.com/r/whbiv7/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update()` method's argument is expected to be a hash. But your `req_data` argument becomes actually a `Request` here:

```
def bookmark_request
 bookmarked_against_Request = Request.first
 ...
 bookmarked_against_Request_2 = bookmarked_against_Request
 ...
end
```

And `Request` class has no `empty?` method. Moreover it might become `nil`, if there are no Requests at all.

Comment: can you tell me how I can correct me. That would be a great help

Comment: is there away that I can pass a whole object and that request will be updated according to object passed ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just need to ask one more thing if I have to update more than one attribute how would I do that meaning should they be comma separated like 
`request.upadte(req_data.attribute, req_data.attribute)`


or should I update every attribute separately

Comment: I tried to do it like you told but it;s giving me this error now 
**undefined method `each_pair' for [BSON::ObjectId('55191e7a6761720bd9020000')]:Array**

Comment: Sorry, I have no expierince with MongoDB, but you can try this: 'request.update(Hash[req_data.attributes])'. Using Activerecord to update multiple attributes you shoud just pass a hash (e.g. {attr1: 123, attr2: 'value' }) to update() or update_attributes() method